# Jekyll collections don't generate pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have been stuck creating a page for my lab-group for the past 6 hours.
The code is in our [GitHub](https://github.com/UTS-Bioinformatics/uts-bioinformatics.github.io/commit/bbe0ef2f46bfc35e8d6e6bf0e2aabc79e83fea1c), and I have been following the [Jekyll docs on Collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/).

Basically, I have edited my `_config.yml` file as follows:

```
collections:
  workshops:
    output: false
```

In the `contents/_workshops/` directory, I created a file

```
title: "Cellular deconvolution"
label: workshops
layout: default
published: true
date: 2023-07-10
---
blah blah
```

Now as far as I know, Jekyll should create a static file for each file in this directory in the `_site` directory upon live-reload. However, it does not do this. I do not understand why though.

I do have a page (`workshops.markdown`, which uses the layout `workshops.html`) that (in the layout) iterates of the workshops collection, and this does render my page title, date and (if I ask it to) the contents of the file on this static page. Therefore, the only issue is the generation of the static page/file in the `_site` directory.

I have followed a bunch of other tutorials and questions/answers on how to fix this as well, but nothing has helped so far. I am pretty sure I am the problem, but I just don't get it.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Jekyll does not like it when a page is named the same as a collection (stored in '/workshops/'). The page will be generated, however, the collection is not (pages are expected to be stored in '/workshops/').
A simple solution is to store the page as '/workshops.html'.